# How to install appexchange apps

Tags: appexchange

Applications that are available in appexchange in salesforce is developed only by using salesforce apex langauage or any other languages like Java,.net..etc .
Apps that are developed by other language can be runned in force.com platform???

Comment: Your title does not match your post. What is your question exactly?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and clarify what you're looking for, and we'll be glad to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/)

Search for an app:

[image]

Select an app, and click "Get it now":

[image]

Log into the Appexchange using your SF Credentials (for the org where you want to install)

[image]

And then follow the instructions...

You can also access the Appexchange from the Setup Page in both Lightning Experience and Classic from within your org.